# How to store formatted strings in a configuration file?

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-2.x, configuration-files, configparser

I am using the `ConfigParser` module in Python 2.6 and I wish to load formatted strings from my configuration file. An example of such a string might be the following:

```
[Section Name]
#in the config file
#tmp_string has value 'string'
my_string = 'This is a %s' % tmp_string
```

Is there a nice way to save such strings in the config file? I am not going to know what the value of the string is until I load the config file, so I can't evaluate it and then save it to the file or anything like that. Obviously at the moment, when I load the string and print it out, I get the following:

```
#config is the ConfigParser
my_string = config.get('Section Name', 'my_string')
print my_string
>>>'This is a %s' % tmp_string
```

I would love to get the output:

```
>>> This is a string
```

How do you achieve this? I would preferably like to stay with `ConfigParser`, but another option may be acceptable. (I know you can't just print the string and have it magically appear how you would like it to, I am just trying to demonstrate what I wish to do.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `tmp_string` is defined in the same section of the config file, then you can reference it in other places in the same section using a special format: `%(variable_name)s`.

So applying it to your example:

`myconfig.cfg` file

```
[Section Name]
tmp_string = string  ; must be in the same section
my_string = This is a %(tmp_string)s
```

Now the value of `tmp_string` will be "[iterpolated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation)" or substituted into the value of `my_string` when it's retrieved:

```
try:
    from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    from configparser import ConfigParser  # Python 3


config = ConfigParser()
print(config.get('Section Name', 'my_string'))
```

Output:

```
This is a string
```

**Note:** Normally values outside the current section can't be referenced. However if they were defined in a special section named `DEFAULT`, their values can be. In other words, the following config file would have produced the same results:

```
[DEFAULT]
tmp_string = string

[Section Name]
my_string = This is a %(tmp_string)s
```

If a name is defined in both the `DEFAULT` section and in the same section as a reference to it, the "local" value in the same section takes precedence and will be the one used.

### Python 3 Changes

The `ConfigParser` *module* was renamed `configparser` and an alternative handler for interpolation which implements a more advanced syntax is available via a new `ExtendedInterpolation` class which added. To enable its use you would need to create an instance of it and use it when instantiating the `ConfigParser` class — which can be done very succinctly by doing both at once like this:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
```

This form of interpolation accept strings with the format: `${section:variable_name}`. Aside from being slightly more readable than `%(variable_name)s`, the looked-up variable can be in *any* specified section, not just a special one named `DEFAULT`. If the `section:` part is left out, the variable name must be in the current section (or the special `DEFAULT` section if there is one).

Answer (score 2):

The same way [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) already explain:

```
my_string='This is a %(tmp_string)s'
```

Answer (score 1):

These days the  [docs](https://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation) also specify a way to use `${}` as your formatter, which I found easier to both read and use, instead of `%()s`.
This is quite simple to achieve:

consider the following config filed, named `.configfile`:

```
[arbitrarySectionName]
tmp_string = any section

[Section Name]
my_string = Now you can read from ${arbitrarySectionName:tmp_string} not just DEFAULT
```

and to interpret this properly you'll do in your module:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
config.read('.configfile')
print(config.get('Section Name', 'my_string'))
```

Output:

> Now you can read from any section not just DEFAULT